# Hardware estimation for Big graph analysis with Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am going to build a big graph with 1 billion nodes and 300 billion relationships. All nodes and relationships have the same type.

I need to get shortest path between two nodes with maximum 6 relationships in between.

shortestPath((n1:node)-[*..6]->(n2:node))

Would somebody help me what hardware I need to have max response time of 1 minute for 100 simultaneous requests?

Comment: did you look at the [hardware calculator](https://neo4j.com/hardware-sizing-calculator/?aliId=15514449) ?. it is provided by the neo4j. you can input your number of nodes and relationships. From that it'll estimate the hardware you might need

Comment: @ShaikRizwana Thanks shaik. Very helpful. Do you have any idea for speed of finding shortest path?